# Group by Clause with Top Record - MYsql

Tags: mysql

I have written the following SQL query which works great

```
SELECT  W.LineItems_LineItemID
     , P.CurrentRate
     , P.CurrentEffectiveDate 
  FROM WorkOrderLineItems W 
  JOIN PayScaleLoaclJObCodes P 
    ON P.JobCodeID = W.LineItems_LineItemID 
 WHERE P.PayScalesLocal_ID = 29
   AND W.WorkOrderCurrent_WorkOrderID = 120420
   AND P.CurrentEffectiveDate <= '2018-05-27' 
 ORDER 
    BY P.CurrentEffectiveDate DESC
```

Shows following results

[image]

Is there a way to return only a single that is the Top record, I do not want to show multiple records only the first record in the resulset

Comment: Yes. ...Limit 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 W.LineItems_LineItemID, P.CurrentRate, P.CurrentEffectiveDate 
  FROM WorkOrderLineItems W 
  JOIN PayScaleLoaclJObCodes P ON P.JobCodeID = W.LineItems_LineItemID 
  WHERE P.PayScalesLocal_ID = 29 AND W.WorkOrderCurrent_WorkOrderID = 120420
  AND P.CurrentEffectiveDate <= '2018-05-27' 
  ORDER BY P.CurrentEffectiveDate DESC
```

The SELECT TOP clause is used to specify the number of records to return. For your case all you would need is `TOP 1` for one.

OR

```
SELECT W.LineItems_LineItemID, P.CurrentRate, P.CurrentEffectiveDate 
  FROM WorkOrderLineItems W 
  JOIN PayScaleLoaclJObCodes P ON P.JobCodeID = W.LineItems_LineItemID 
  WHERE P.PayScalesLocal_ID = 29 AND W.WorkOrderCurrent_WorkOrderID = 120420
  AND P.CurrentEffectiveDate <= '2018-05-27' 
  ORDER BY P.CurrentEffectiveDate DESC 
  LIMIT 1
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 W.LineItems_LineItemID, P.CurrentRate, P.CurrentEffectiveDate FROM WorkOrderLi' at line 1

Comment: @user580950 do you get that error when you take out `W.LineItems_LineItemID, P.CurrentRate, P.CurrentEffectiveDate` ? What verson of sql are you using?

Comment: @user580950 also try out that new one I just edited in

Comment: mysql version 5.6.39-log

Comment: If I remove this W.LineItems_LineItemID, P.CurrentRate, P.CurrentEffectiveDate same error